# Why are my liquid particles so HUGE?

Tags: physics, mantaflow

[image]

Im trying to make a wine-pouring scene but somehow the particles come out huge. I made everything accurate to real-life scale so why is this happening? My understanding of liquid domains are quite poor...

Here is the blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14visBBc9YyAL1f3viMbaKa6kWuKz5u0D/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make fluid simulation i would recommend first to watch some beginner tutorials. There are a lot of good tutorials on yt.

Also you can just give "quick liquid" to the default cube. And watch what happens. Then you can change one or two parameter...and watch and learn what happens.
What i don't recommend is: Just assuming that if you take "real world" measurements and default settings and then "hope" it will work.

Now back to your case:

If you "forget" about the real world size and resize all your objects with factor 10 and give your objects also some solidify modifiers so that the water doesn't come out of "everywhere" but so that the effector can work and if you raise your resolution to 100...you can get this:

[image]

[image]

blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppaiiqpfiv0r2fs/Wine%20pouring_solved.blend?dl=0

Comment: Somehow i still cannot for the life of me get the the same result. Do you mind sharing the file?

Comment: i added the blend file

Comment: so I don't get what were the different steps you did to fix it?

Comment: Right after „back to your case“: resize…solidify modifier…resolution.